# How to change from ubuntu 21.04 to 20.04? Also what did I install?

Tags: 20.04, 21.04

I have never used any linux. Install from window 10. Ubuntu 21.04 and it has no wifi icon and cannot conmect internet. Cannot open videos from my external hard disk. Cannot type in text. Keyboard is recognized because I can type my password and at the terminal. 
I used Rufus and usb to install 21.04. Now rufus cannot execute on linux. I borrowed friend's laptop and Rufus cannot select or does not support 20.04 version which I download from ubuntu.com with my ipad coz my laptop has no internet. I think 20.04 might be stable. My laptop is Dell, i7.
What did I install? Like window, do I have install drivers?? For that I might need internet, right?

Comment: Aww...I also tried like that cmd -something network-manager start or restart. It said network-manager is not installed.

Comment: If you stick to *released* products they are *stable*.   I'm using Ubuntu *impish* which will be released as 21.10 in October-2021 but until then it's treated as *unstable*.  Ubuntu 20.04 is *stable* (20.04, 20.04.1, 20.04.2 as they've been released), and whilst there are *unstable* **daily** images for Ubuntu *focal* (ie. what will be 20.04.3 on release) they're unlikely what you mean.  Both Ubuntu 20.04 LTS & Ubuntu 21.04 are *stable*.  Code names (*focal*, *impish*) are used for *unstable* releases until actual release (ie. when deemed *stable*).

Comment: Ubuntu has automatic tools that *release upgrade* or bump you from one release to the next (eg. from 21.04 they'll bump you to 21.10 after it's released & *stable*), but not backwards.  LTS releases have two *release-upgrade* choices, the next release (ie. 20.04 to 20.10) or to the next LTS (20.04 to 22.04 after 22.04.1 has been released) but you'll note they are both forward moving.   To go backwards a re-install is required (ie. boot installation media & install).

Comment: To fix wifi issues, trouble shooting documentation exists (eg. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Devices & others) which allows you to find clues online or provide details so we can help you), as well as for adding *codecs* so media is recognized where it requires *non-free blobs* (ie. closed source) again documentation will help you with that..

Comment: I need 10 reputation for image. I downloaded fron ubuntu.com but I want to make sure that this time I download the stable version if trouble shoot does not work. Can you show me download link.

Comment: Download link for what?  https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/ and you can follow links or maybe https://ubuntu.com/download   All released versions are *stable* so it's unlikely you'll be downloading an unreleased *unstable* version following normal links.

Answer (score 0):

I got wifi wireless network. It was just wireless network and I can still connect internet with wire.(Honestly I did not know that till today. )From that I download drivers and update somethings.Then there was icon on top right conor. Yes I cannot play videos. For that I downloaded VLC. But I kinda miss GOM player. Sadly I cannot find her.
I made mistakes. I could write text. There was a white hightlight line which blocked my words. I thought I couldnot write any words. Sorry about that.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. You are most welcome to answer your own question. However, this answer does not provide any solution to your question. When you have new information to share about the question, please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1347844/edit) and the new information. In this site it is best to ask one question at a time. See the [site help](https://askubuntu.com/help) for guidelines on how to ask questions and answer them.